# Do there exist $d$-regular expander families with Cheeger constant greater than $d/2$?

Tags: graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory

## Definitions.

For a finite simple graph $G=(V, E)$, the **Cheeger constant** for $G$ is defined as
$$
h(G) = \inf_{S} \frac{e(S, S^c)}{\min\{|S|, |S^c|\}}
$$
where $S$ runs over all non-empty proper subsets of $V$, $e(S, S^c)$ is the number of edges with one end-point in $S$ and the other end-point in $S^c$.
The Cheeger constant is a measure of connectivity of the graph.
The higher the Cheeger constant, the more connected the graph is.

A $d$-regular **expander family** is a sequence $G_1, G_2, G_3, \ldots$ of finite simple $d$-regular graphs such that:
$\bullet$ $|V(G_n)|\to \infty$ as $n\to \infty$, and
$\bullet$there exists a positive constant $c$ such that $h(G_n)>c$ for all $n$.

(It is intuitively repugnant that such a family exists, since the graphs become sparser and sparser, but still remain highly connected.)

## Question.

It is a theorem (Marcus, Spielman, and Srivastava) that for any $d$, there is a $d$-regular expander family $G_1, G_2, G_3, ...$ such that $h(G_n)\geq (d-2\sqrt{d-1})/2$ for all $n$.

> **Question.** Is there some $d$ (or preferably a family of $d$'s) for which it is known that there is a $d$-regular expander family $G_1, G_2, G_3, \ldots$ such that $h(G_n)>d/2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No no such family exists.
This is a rough sketch of the proof: Let $G$ be an *arbitrary* $d$-regular graph. Each $v \in G$ flips a fair coin independently of the other vertices, heads it is in $S$ then tails it is in $\bar{S}$.

Then on the one hand, with probability $1-\frac{1}{n}$ both $|S|$ and $\bar{S}$ have at least $\frac{n-\log n\sqrt{n}}{2}$ vertices each.

Then on the other hand, the expected fraction of edges $e$ with one endpoint of $e$ in $S$ and the other in $\bar{S}$ is only $\frac{1}{2}$.
So as the least it can be is 0, [you can show that] with probability at least $\frac{1}{\log n}$ the number of edges $E$ with one endpoint in $S$ and the other in $\bar{S}$ is only $\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{\log n}$.

Thus the above randomized algorithm returns with positive probability e.g., at least $\frac{1}{\log n}-\frac{1}{n}$ a set $S$ s.t. $S,\bar{S}$ s.t. $\frac{e(S,\bar{S}}{\min\{|S|,|\bar{S}|\}} \le \frac{d}{2}+o(1)$. So at least the lim inf of the Cheeger constant of an infinite family of $d$-regular graphs cannot be greater than $\frac{d}{2}$.

---

OR this would be another way to prove the answer is no: Partition $V(G)$ into two sets $S$ and $T$ of equal cardinality (exactly equal to within one vertex). If more than $\frac{d|S|}{2} + d^2$ edges of $G$ have one endpoint in $S$ and the other in $T$ then there are two nonadjacent vertices $u \in S$ and $v \in T$; $u$ and $v$ not adjacent in $G$, s.t. more than $d/2$ neighbours of $u$ are in $T$ and more than $d/2$ neighbours of $v$ are in $S$. So take $u$ out of $S$ and put $u$ into $T$ and take $v$ out of $T$  nd put $v$ into $S$.Then the resulting sets $S'$ and $T'$ still partition $V(G)$ and have equal cardinality, but $e(S,T') < e(S,T)$ [strict inequality].

Comment: Hi Mike. I was going through your answer again. Can you give me a hint as to how to prove that with probability (at least?) $1-1/n$ both $S$ and $\bar S$ have at least $(n-\log(n\sqrt n))/2$ vertices. Thanks.

Comment: I apologize @caffeinemachine I had written this ambiguously...you have $\frac{n-\sqrt{n}\log n}{2}$ vertices on each side. Which is still close enough to $\frac{n}{2}$. [The idea is that if you flip a fair coin $n$ times you will get $\frac{n-\sqrt{n}\log n}{2}$ heads.]

Comment: I still don't follows. Are you using Chebychef's inequality? Also, the expression in your comment is different from the expression in the answer. In the comment you have "$(n-\sqrt{n}\log n)/2$" while in the answer you have "$(n-\log(n\sqrt n))/2$".

Comment: A. If you flip a fair coin $n$ times then you can calculate *directly* that $P$[you get less than $\frac{n-\sqrt{n} \log n}{2}$ of either heads OR tails] is no more than $\frac{1}{n}$. You can show using MArkov that $P$[there are only at most a $\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{\log n}$-fraction of edsges w one endpoint in $S$ and the other in $T$] is at least $\frac{1}{\log n}$.

Comment: Thus the events $\{$both $|S|$ and $|T|$ are at least $\frac{n-\sqrt{n}\log n}{2} \}$ and $\{$no more than $\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{\log n}$-fraction of the edges of $G$ are between $S$ and $T\}$ will happen *together* with probability at least $\frac{1}{\log n}-\frac{1}{n}$ which is positive.

Comment: Anyway IT should be $\frac{n-\sqrt{n}\log n}{2}$ [which is still fine and a strong enough bound] and NOT $...\log(\sqrt{n} \log n)$. I had mistyped

Comment: ...nor $\log (n\sqrt{n})$

Comment: I am sorry but I still don't get this. Let $f(n) = \sqrt{n}\log{n}$. Then the probability that one gets at most $(n-f(n))/2$ heads in $n$ coin tosses is $\frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{i=0}^{(n-f(n))/2}\binom{n}{i}$. I am unable to estimate the summation. Can you give a hint?